# iPod Nano hangs after sync when attempting to play a podcast

Tags: ipod, podcasts, freeze

After synchronising my iPod nano (2G I think) it will without fail hang if the first thing I attempt to play is a podcast. I can resolve this by resetting it, by flicking the lock switch and holding down Menu and the select button on the clickwheel.

However if I play a music track, then a podcast after a sync then it doesn't hang. Is there anything else I can try so I don't have to keep resetting it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [restoring](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1339) your iPod? In iTunes, just select your iPod and click 'Restore'. Depending on if you have done it before or not, iTunes will download the firmware image for your iPod and reset it back to its factory condition. Usually, this will fix all problems. If not, try contacting [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com).

Comment: No I hadn't thought of doing that, I'll give it a go tonight and see what happens.

Comment: If you're using the ipod as a flash drive, don't forget to backup your files. Restore will erase everything.

Comment: I have had the same problem for 3 years (damn tough piece of hardware!). Resetting does no good, neither does installing new firmware.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a mal-formed mp3 file. It happens with just one particular podcast?